# Building maps using ESRI shapefile

Tags: tool-request, geospatial

I would like to combine together a couple of ESRI shapefile shared by the city of Toronto. After doing a quick search I found plenty of tutorials to use those file in programming language (R, php, python ...).

I know that [fusion table](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2592829?hl=fr) kind of support them, but I am looking for other options that doesn't requiere too much coding.

Comment: convert them to .geojson/.topojson and use leaflet.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite is [cartodb](https://cartodb.com/). It is free and you can create wonderful visualizations.

Also, you can read this [tutorial](http://www.geospatialtraining.com/blog/index.php/importing-esri-shapefiles-to-cartodb/) about using ESRI shapefiles in cartodb.

Comment: thanks - cartodb free plan is limited to 5MB while I need about 15MB :(

Comment: Keep an eye on them, because they use to announce Online courses and they provide a life-academic account for anyone to apply for free in the course. An academic account has more than 5MB.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a simple GUI to interact with shapefiles (plot maps, see properties and do some manipulation) you can use the free/libre software [QGIS](http://qgis.org/).
If you want more control and a programmable interface you can go with [Python using libraries such as fiona and shapely](http://macwright.org/2012/10/31/gis-with-python-shapely-fiona.html).
And if you want to display your shapes in the Web, I highly recommend the JavaScript library [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/). In this case, the preferred format to use is GeoJSON (you can convert [shapefiles to GeoJSON with fiona and shapely](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/a-python-guide-for-open-data-file-formats/1210#1210)).

Comment: QGIS is an excellent resource and doesn't require coding to do basic cartography.

Comment: "Too much coding" is different from "no coding".

Comment: you don't need to know any coding to use qgis. open it up -> open up the shapefiles -> save to whatever format you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FME Desktop (trial) for merge a couple of Esri Shapefiles.
[FME Safe](http://www.safe.com/)