# Where can I find a database of hotel property locations?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Looking for an open database of lat/long co-ordinates for hotels. I am aware of sites like Factual.com but I'm looking for something more open.

Comment: maybe try www.hotels-database.com/en

Comment: @clodluc : From their [legal terms page](http://www.hotels-database.com/en/content/2-mentions-legales) : "Any representation, reproduction, modification, commercial use, including any transfers to another site are strictly prohibited without written authorisation, to be requested by mail at the address indicated above. Only strictly personal use is authorised. Any representation, reproduction or use, including partial use, by any means whatsoever without the expressed written consent of www.hotels-database.com is prohibited and illegal. ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [long discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis) from 2009 on StackOverflow which you may find helpful.

In particular, I'd check out the [Expedia Affiliate Network](http://developer.ean.com/docs/geo-functions/) or try to get [TripAdvisor](http://help.tripadvisor.com/articles/200615497) access.

... And maybe [api.hotelbase.org](http://api.hotelsbase.org/documentation.php) will come back some day.

Comment: This is not open data. Also, detailing the pros, cons and access methods of each option (as separate answers) would be much better than this links-only answer.

Answer (score 10):

OpenStreetMap (OSM) to the rescue, I would say. According the the OSM Wiki, hotels can be found within the database by the tag [`tourism=hotel`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Hotel).

A quick check using the Overpass API, shown here for an excerpt of [Rome, Italy](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/2IG); result:

153 nodes (hotels) only in the visible area, tagged with name, operator, website, phone number. YMMV, depending on exact location.

Comment: cool answer. would you be willing to post a short answer regarding how to use the OSM API? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/a-web-api-users-guide-for-free-and-open-data

Comment: TripAdvisor shows 1,264 hotels in Rome: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g187791-Rome_Lazio-Hotels.html - that's roughly 8x what OSM shows.

Comment: The difference is that OSM provides Open Data, TripAdvisor not so much …

Answer (score 4):

While OSM is the most obvious place for *open data* about hotels, the second best place might be [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org).

The data is available as CSV under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License:
https://github.com/baturin/wikivoyage-listings

Notes:

- Wikivoyage's goal is not to list ALL hotels, but to list for each destination about 10 hotels in each of 3 price ranges. Hotels are selected for value and cachet by Wikivoyage editors in a democratic and usually unbiased process. That might suit your purpose better than an indiscriminate list which would also contain unrecommended hotels.
- Not all hotels have GPS coordinates yet.
- We do not run the tool often, so the data files are probably quite old. But it is open source and can be run by anyone. Maintainers welcome!
- Formats: CSV, KML, GPX, OBF (OpenStreetMap), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would start. I would contact the customer support for each major hotel chain and inquire on how to make a request for a copy of all their locations in electronic format (e.g., CSV file). If you get any datasets, post them somewhere (e.g., github) and leave a link here for the rest of us to use.

Comment: That's a good approach for US where there are a lot of chain hotels, but elsewhere (e.g. Europe) a large percentage of the market is independent owners.

Comment: Getting each chain to send their data under an *open license* would at best take years. Anyway, whoever manage to get some, putting it on Github would be great indeed, especially for re-use in OSM.

Answer (score 2):

Uncertain what your geographic interests are but for US take a look at data from Rutgers U. It's free and open for non-commercial uses. Data is available by state so you'll probably have to download 50 or so files.

The data has detailed information about businesses. You could search by Standard Industry Code for hotels. Some records have lat/long - most do not.

Use an online bulk geo coder to get lat/long.

Uncertain how up-to-date or complete the data is.

Comment: Got a link to data set?

Answer (score -1):

You can negotiate to buy all worldwide hotels data from

[www.lodgingeo.com](http://www.lodgingeo.com)

They actually have collected almost all planet accommodation properties. It is not free, but it is the most affordable. The database is comprehensive with contact details and hotels images.

(Note: I am affiliated with this site)

Comment: It seems to be a test website now. Also, opendata.stackexchange.com is about open data :-)