# Sports Clubs & Facilities

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, sports, geocoding

I want to create a website with which people can easily find sports clubs or facilities in their area.

I basically need a list/database of all sports clubs and facilities in the world. If there is only data available from certain regions/cities, these would be useful as well.

Data should preferably include:

- Address or Latitude + Longitude
- Sport (e.g. Tennis)
- Name of club / facility

(additional data such as email,website,phone etc. would be welcomed)

Thank you for your help.

PS: If anybody is interested in helping actively please contact me

Comment: I think you can use OpenStreetMap (OSM), which is often an answer on this site ([example](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1707/1511)).

Answer (score 2):

A handful of local governments offer datasets like this:

- Recreational facilities in San Francisco: https://data.sfgov.org/d/z76i-7s65
- Various datasets in Denver:

  - https://www.denvergov.org/opendata/search?tag=recreation
  - https://www.denvergov.org/opendata/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-recreational-court-surfaces
- Recreational facilities in Washington DC: http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/7122c1c815314588abe5c1864da8a355_3
- Golf courses in NY State: https://data.ny.gov/d/cgck-srxx

I don't think you're gonna be able to find a nationwide dataset that has a field for the type of sport available at a particular facility.